# Convert SRText To PROJ4TEXT

Tags: postgis-2.0, proj

I'd like to convert the following for updating my spatial_ref_sys table.

```
PROJCS["USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-96.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",23.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

The matching [spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6703](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6703/) link for this item seems to come up blank. Also, tried `gdalsrsinfo` but it errored with `ERROR 6: No translation for Albers to PROJ.4 format is known.`

How do I translate the above for that field? Any other tools to get a full, proper INSERT statement for inserting the proper data into spatial_ref_sys?

UPDATE: The above data comes from the 2 PRJ files found in http://www.america2050.org/maps/, third link to the ZIP files. I would like to import these maps into my database to run queries against some data.

Comment: could you use http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2163/ instead?

Comment: I don't have enough experience with GIS to make that call. On what basis do we determine equality between two specifications?

Comment: one is a standard and the other is user submitted? compare the numbers? may be you need to edit your question to give us some more clues and background

Comment: I would love to supply more info, but not sure what would be informative. I added the link to where the data came from. Anything else I can supply?

Comment: The one you have was originally defined by Esri. EPSG::5070 is equivalent (except for the names)   @iant Spatialreference.org's 2163 isn't equivalent. It uses Lambert azimuthal equal area instead.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get the proj4text for spatial_ref_sys from knowing it is EPSG::5070? I checked spatialreference.org for anything with a 5070 and came up matches that do not inspire confidence. And, most of them don't have a proj4 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection is officially known as EPSG:5070 and included in the EPSG registry and the latest GDAL builds since version 1.9. It is not included in spatialreference.org, because that site has been lacking care for some time.

SR-ORG:6703 is not an official code that GDAL or PROJ.4 will know.

You can run `gdalsrsinfo epsg:5070` and it returns:

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["NAD83 / Conus Albers",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",23],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","5070"]]
```

The reason why your first attempt fails is because ESRI names the projection `Albers`, and PROJ.4 does not know that it is the same as `Albers_Conic_Equal_Area`.

If you want to build shapefiles from your Postgis database, I suggest to use the OGC WKT naming, not the ESRI one. Otherwise someone else will run into the same trouble as you.

Comment: How or where does one learn how to write a valid SRText or PROJ4TEXT for a custom CRS with custom SRID?

Comment: Take a valid CRS defined by EPSG with the same projection, run gdalsrsinfo on it and study the parameters. Then just exchange the parameter values to get your custom CRS correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When I open those files in QGis the srs is epsg:5070 - and the boundaries seem to be in the right place (when compared to a known good 4326 states file).

[image]

Comment: It seems like prj2epsg.org coughs up 5070 too.

Answer (score 0):

The proj4txt unofficially seems to be `"+proj=aea +lon_0=-96 +lat_0=23 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +datum=NAD83"` gathered from [this link](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2011-August/030406.html). For any future websurfer, here's the insert query I used:

```
INSERT into public.spatial_ref_sys (
srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext
) 
VALUES ( 
95070, 
'<insert an identifier>', 
95070, 
'+proj=aea +lon_0=-96 +lat_0=23 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +datum=NAD83', 
'PROJCS["USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-96.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",23.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'
);
```